# DataGrid calls CancelEdit when OnPropertyChanged is called

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, inotifypropertychanged

I have a simple `DataGrid` which is bound to a `CollectionViewSource.View`.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollectionViewSource.View, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Model.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}"
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The `CollectionViewSource.Source` is equal to an `ObservableCollection<ViewModel>`.

```
private CollectionViewSource _myCollectionViewSource= new CollectionViewSource();
public CollectionViewSource MyCollectionViewSource
{
    get { return _myCollectionViewSource; }
    set { _myCollectionViewSource= value; }
}
public MainViewModel(ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> coll)
{
    MyCollectionViewSource.Source = coll;
}
```

My `ItemViewModel` class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `IEditableObject`.

```
public class ItemViewModel : ViewModelBase, IEditableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

For some reason, when I call `OnPropertyChanged("SomeObjectInsideViewModel");` the `ViewModel`'s `CancelEdit` is called.

Why would `CancelEdit` be called when something inside my `ViewModel`changes?

Comment: The binding engine calls CancelEdit as a notification EVEN THOUGH you issued the notification because you subscribed to it.  It is telling you that the item is no longer synch'd up with with changes on the UI because you changed it (even if there are no changes on the UI).  Your code looks fine, but remember that the DataGridTextColumn binds two-ways by default so your Xaml declaration is redundant.  Same for LostFocus, it's the default.

Comment: @GayotFow How would I make it call `CancelEdit` **only** when the user actually cancels changes? _(ie. pressing the `Esc` key.)_ My problem is that I don't want the changes to revert when a user presses tab, enter, or clicks on another cell. It should instead call `EndEdit`.
Thanks for pointing out the redundant code, but it's there as my sanity check. :P

Comment: In that case, you'll need to instrument your ViewModel to maintain state before and after your call to OnPropertyChanged.